# Forward a shell command using python

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, optionparser

So to be more precise, what I am trying to do is :

- read a full shell command as argument of my python script like : `python myPythonScript.py ls -Fl`
- Call that command within my python script when I'd like to (Make some loops on some folders and apply the command etc ...)

I tried this :

```
import subprocess
from optparse import OptionParser
from subprocess import call
def execCommand(cmd):
        call(cmd)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        parser = OptionParser()
        (options,args) = parser.parse_args()
        print args
        execCommand(args)
```

The result is that now I can do python `myPythonScript.py ls` , but I don't know how to add options. I know I can use `parser.add_option` , but don't know how to make it work for all options as I don't want to make only specific options available, but all possible options depending on the command I am running.
Can I use something like `parser.add_option('-*')`  ? How can I parse the options then and call the command with its options ?

**EDIT**

I need my program to parse all type of commands passed as argument : `python myScript.py ls -Fl` , `python myScript.py git pull`, `python myScript rm -rf *` etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OptionParser` is useful when your own program wants to process the arguments: it helps you turn string arguments into booleans or integers or list items or whatever. In your case, you just want to pass the arguments on to the program you're invoking, so don't bother with `OptionParser`. Just pass the arguments as given in `sys.argv`.

```
subprocess.call(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I needed, do you have some documentation about sys, as I may want to manipulate the arguments a bit.

Comment: Oh, it's my first time using python, I just realised sys is the basic way to read arguments. Thank you. I tried the code with `python myScript.py cd -`, but It returned an error. Do you know why maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much your program depends on command line arguments, you can go with simple route.

### Simple way of reading command line arguments

Use `sys` to obtain all the arguments to python command line.

```
import sys
print  sys.argv[1:]
```

Then you can use `subprocess` to execute it.

```
from subprocess import call
# e.g. call(["ls", "-l"])
call(sys.argv[1:])
```

This sample below works fine for me.

```
import sys 
from subprocess import call
print(sys.argv[1:])
call(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: This applies when I know the kind of options I want to call, I need my program to parse all type of commands passed as argument : `python myScript.py ls -Fl` , `python myScript.py git pull`, `python myScript rm -rf *` etc ...

Comment: Added the sample with 'subprocess' in the body.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this wouldn't work with `python myScript.py cd ..` for example ?